# Is it possible to use a single input in different objects?

Tags: java

The both codes below are from different class files.

I'm trying to use the input from spinWheels for pull.

Is that possible?

```
public int spinWheels(int betAmt)
{
    String[] aWheel = new String[5];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    betAmt = kb.nextInt();
}


public void pull(int bet)
{
    betAmt = bet;
    totalcoins = totalcoins - bet;
}
```

Comment: How do you call that code? It's not quite clear what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Gabe! Yes, it is possible to use information from one class in another class. I'm not saying this to be mean, but that's a pretty core Java concept, and your question and code show a fundamental misunderstanding of how the language works. Stack Overflow is designed for specific questions rather than discussion/guided tutorial, so it may not be the best place for you for now. It looks like you're creating a slot machine simulator for a CS 101 class; I'd encourage you to read _The Java Tutorials_ or your textbook, and come back when you have a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
int x = 0;
spinWheels(x);
pull(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but there are several things that you must do first. Say you have a class A:

```
class A{
    public int spinWheels(int betAmt)
    {
        String[] aWheel = new String[5];
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        return kb.nextInt(); //I assume you need this value later
        //you must return an int here
     }
}
```

and you have a second class B:

```
 class B{
     public void pull()
     {
       //you need a reference to an Object of type A
       A a = new A();       
       bet = a.spinWheels();
       totalcoins = totalcoins - bet;
     }
 }
```

Of course the above code is very simplistic, without knowing what you want to achieve it is not possible to say more.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
public int spinWheels()
{
    String[] aWheel = new String[5];
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(kb.nextInt());
    ...
}
```

I don't understand why you'd want to pass betAmt as an argument if you're going to run it over anyway...